# How do I transform bones without deforming the armature?

Tags: armature, bones, transforms

I’m trying to rotate a bone in edit mode so I can use it with this add on called spring bones which basically makes bones… well… springy. The add on requires bones to be rotated a certain way to get a certain result. I’m trying to rotate a bone so I can get the bones to spring another way. I’ve tried unchecking the deform check box but that just cancelled the effect altogether. So how can I transform bones without effecting the mesh at all?

[Blend file + addon](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1pPelO8sAOTMoNH526VSMq1bpmDjgchHE?usp=sharing)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends by the rig structure, it's impossible to tell without seeing the rig, but you can add a bone in edit mode, put it in the same location as the bone you want to rotate, set its rotation as desired and make it parent of the previous bone, so that the spring effect will be transferred. You will have to set the new bone as child of the parent the previous bone had. It may not work, depending by the rig structure. If you need more infos please upload your file, the addon and its rotation requests.